# Dragging, resizing and rotating an image over layers in Openlayers3

Tags: javascript, image, openlayers, openlayers-3

I would like to be able to **drag, resize and rotate an image over layers** on Openlayers3. The image has to be independent from layers.
I tried rendering the image as a layer, using this:

```
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());

var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({opacity: 0.5});
var imageSource = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
    url: 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/faf7fa/0011ff',
    imageExtent: extent
});

imageLayer.setSource(imageSource);
map.addLayer(imageLayer);
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find any clue about the possibility to drag an image layer over others layers.

Moreover, **I do not want to load the image as a HTML element**. I want it to be part of the OL canvas.

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Is this what you are seeking https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html?

Comment: Hey artgb, thanks for your reply. This is not exactly what I want to do.
[This example](http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.geoimage.html) from Svinjica reply is what I want to do.

Comment: Happy to hear that you got answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like [this](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.geoimage.html) can point you in right direction. It's not so flexible as you would like but it can help you a bit.

Comment: Hey, Svinjica. This is an excellent direction you gave me. Indeed, I will make something more visual than this example by putting overlays over it so the users can interact directly with the image.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @E.Boussardon glad I could help, enjoy :)

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: @DavidMorales thx for pointing that out. Now is fixed, enjoy :)